# asp.net mvc long operation

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

i need create an email list sending to many emails. what is best solution in mvc to call long time operation? better with example

Comment: it is a virtual hosting, i need a solution exactly on it, but it allow only asp.net

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would suggest that you save the messages you want to send in a DB for example, along with the recipients. Then, you can use a scheduler (like [Quartz.NEt](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/)) that checks every one minute (for example) if there are emails to be sent and in case there are, it sends up to 10 mails every time.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to run long processes like this on your web server. You want a "backoffice" application to handle sending emails and responses.  Write another application that runs on a different computer. Have it read the information necessary from the database and send the emails.  If you're sending emails you'll also need to handle the responses. This backoffice application should handle both.

Answer (score 1):

Likely you will need to do the following:-

1. Create a Queue where you can put
   jobs to run
2. Create an service
   that processes this queue
3. Maybe report progress from the service
   back to the web site application
4. Maybe report progress back to the
   user of the web application either
   on page refresh or more dynamically using Ajax

Some options for each of these components:-

1) Options for the job queue include an in memory queue Queue<>, a queue stored in a database, an MSMQ, a remote queue like Amazon's simple message queue.  Which you chose will depend on how fault-tolerant you want the solution to be, whether you want to restart after a failure, and whether you need to distribute the work to multiple servers.

2) Options for the service include a thread within your web application or an NT Service.  Again this will depend on your needs for fault-tolerance and restartability.

3) How you report progress back will depend on what kind of queue you used.  For MSMQ you might have 'correlated' messages going back the other way.  For a database queue you might mark the progress in the database.  Or you might be calling a web service on the web application to report progress.

4) If you want a dynamic progress bar (or such like) to be shown to the user as the job progresses you can implement an Ajax service that passes the progress information from server to browser.

For sending email messages I would recommend using a database as your queue because you will likely want to be tracking them over a long period of time and marking undeliverable emails, emails that have been read, and such like in your database.

Answer (score -1):

If you can employ ASP.NET MVC2, I'd use the new [Asynchronous Controller](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598%28VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: I didn't down vote but I can see why someone did: Sending many emails would easily exceed the time limit before the browser times-out so it really doesn't help in this case.  Async controller helps use threads more efficiently in a 'stressed' site but doesn't help if one request is going to take longer than the browser is prepared to wait.